# Jquery Load Page in the same domain

Tags: jquery, ajax, screen-scraping, same-origin-policy

I've been trying to load an URL using JQuery's .load() function.

I have an URL - 
https://stanfordwho.stanford.edu/SWApp/authSearch.do?search=pra**&stanfordonly=checkbox&affilfilter=everyone&filters=closed

That I'm on and I 'd like to call this - `$("#StanfordProfile h2").load("https://stanfordwho.stanford.edu/SWApp/authSearch.do?search=Ajay%20Prakash&stanfordonly=checkbox&affilfilter=everyone&filters=closed")`

The selector works when I'm on the second page, but it's not working when I try the above command.
I thought this would work because I'm loading from another page on the same website (as in I shouldn't be coming across a problem due to the same-origin policy).

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try with a url excluding the domain

```
$("#StanfordProfile h2").load("/SWApp/authSearch.do?search=Ajay%20Prakash&stanfordonly=checkbox&affilfilter=everyone&filters=closed");
```

Comment: that doesn't work- interestingly, when I try my line of code with elements that are present in the current document the stuff in the current returns

Comment: can you confirm that `$('#StanfordProfile h2')` exists and that in firebug the request returns without errors (i.e. no JS errors or HTTP errors)?

Comment: yes, it's fine- I've tried it on the page that I'm trying to scrape from

Comment: hmmm... i'm at a loss then. If the URL returns data correctly and the element `$('#StanfordProfile h2')` exists them I'm out of ideas

Comment: Can you try `$.get('/SWApp/authSearch.do?search=Ajay%20Prakash&stanfordonly=checkbox&affilfilter=everyone&filters=closed', function(data) { alert(data); });`

Comment: that works- can I use selectors on the contents of the data property? how?